# How do I animate low poly water?

Tags: animation, modifiers, physics

[image: Low poly water]

So I'm trying to make a low poly well and I wanted to make the water first. I don't want to have just a blue plane, I want it to actually move like water. How do I get some waves on it? It should have small waves since it's just a well not an ocean.

Comment: Try adding the ocean modifier. I don't have a computer in front of me right now, but if you don't have an answer before I get back I'll clarify it a bit more.

Comment: The ocean doesn't move and is huge

Comment: @Rex to make ocean move, you have to keyframe the time parameter, and then bake the ocean. But it's not thought for low poly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you wish, one basic way could be using a wave modifier with a texture, maybe?

[image]

edit: to make only top vertices assign them to a vertex group, and set that "vertex group" name in the modifier:

[image]

Comment: How do I make only the top move? the water doesn't stay in the pond, it "Jumps" out

Comment: @Rex assign all vertices intended for moving (only those of the top face I presume) to a vertex group, then select the vertex group name in the wave modifier. I'll add an example gif.